# Interface visibility restriction, but runs fine

Tags: java, interface, visibility, inner-classes

When designing a fluid API, sometimes I want to use Interface return types so that the caller can easily follow the available methods or gets compiler errors if he does not (the [Step Builder pattern](http://rdafbn.blogspot.nl/2012/07/step-builder-pattern_28.html) is an example).

But when I want to use interfaces just to point to the next available method, like:

```
package packageone;

public class SomeClass implements CanPrint {
    private SomeClass() {

    }

    public static CanPrint get() {
        return new SomeClass();
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Runs fine!");
    }
}

public interface CanPrint {//Compile error: must be defined in own file
    public void print();
}
```

However, firing up a quick test works fine (the following code prints "Runs fine!"):

```
package packagetwo;

import packageone.CanPrint;
import packageone.SomeClass;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CanPrint returnType = SomeClass.get();
        returnType.print();
    }
}
```

The compiler can be 'fooled' by wrapping the entire class:

```
package packageone;

public class Wrapper {
    public static CanPrint get() {
        return SomeClass.get();
    }

    public static class SomeClass implements CanPrint {

        public static CanPrint get() {
            return new SomeClass();
        }

        private SomeClass() {

        }

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Runs fine!");
        }
    }

    public interface CanPrint {
        public void print();
    }
}
```

So currently when I want to keep the interfaces in the same place as the only code that is intended to use it (as the caller only needs the method), I wrap it in a wrapper class which only points to the same method in the inner class.

Why is this restriction in place? The other class can import the interface, use it, even implement their own version if they desire to do so. All of this seems to run without problems. Yet it does not compile.

Note: I've simplified my examples as much as I could, but because of this it might be less clear why one would choose this design.

Comment: I don't get it. How did you run it if it didn't compile in the first place?

Comment: You can't make two top-level entities in one file in Java. Java is more purely object-oriented than many other popular languages like C++. A class file is meant to represent a single entity or idea. You could either put the interface inside the class (thus making it `SomeClass.CanPrint` or put it in its own file.

I've made this a comment because I'm not sure if this addresses the question.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Ran it with Eclipse

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Another violation of the Java standard by Eclipse. It is infamous for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this restriction in place?

It makes it easier for the compiler and humans to find the source file containing a top-level class.

You can expose the interface by:

- Placing the interface in a separate file, like `ISomeClassCanPrint`.
- Or nesting the interface in the class that returns an instance. Your wrapper is close to this approach.

Here's another example of a nested interface:

```
    public static class SomeClassFactory {
      public interface CanPrint {
        public void print();
      }

      public static CanPrint get() {
        return new SomeClass();
      }

      public static class SomeClass implements CanPrint {
        @Override
        public void print() {
          System.out.println("Runs fine!");
        }
      }
    }
```

### More detail

The restriction is covered by the [Java Language Specification, section 7.6: Top level type declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).
>
> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a Java compiler to find a named class within a package. In practice, many programmers choose to put each class or interface type in its own compilation unit, whether or not it is public or is referred to by code in other compilation units.

So while you are allowed to declare multiple *top-level* classes in a single file, at most one can be exposed for access outside the file.

You can, however, expose as many nested classes as you want.